# Pass TDateTime value to OleVariant property through RTTI

Tags: datetime, delphi, rtti, variant

When I assign a `TDateTime` value to `OleVariant` property of an object using RTTI, object becomes Float value.

The object is designed so that this property can become either Null or value of any data type. If it becomes float, then result should be calculated as a difference of floats. If it becomes `TDateTime`, then result should be calculated as a difference of two `TDateTime` values.

Would I have passed the value directly to it, it will work fine, but there is RTTI in the middle.

I know that `TDateTime` is internally repersented as float, but is there a possibility to receive exactly the data type that I send?

Please look at the `tkVariant` case in following sample of code:

```
class procedure TRTTI.SetObjPropValue(obj: TObject; rprop: TRttiProperty; value: OleVariant);
var
  rtyp: TRttiType;
  vt: TVarType;
begin
  if obj = nil then Exit();
  if (rprop <> nil) and (rprop.IsWritable) then begin
    case rprop.PropertyType.TypeKind of
      tkInteger, tkInt64:
        begin
          value := TVarConv.NullableCurr(value);
          if VarIsNumeric(value) then rprop.SetValue(obj, TValue.FromVariant(Trunc(value)));
        end;
      tkFloat:
        begin
          if rprop.PropertyType.Name = 'TDateTime' then
            value := TVarConv.NullableDateTime(value)
          else
            value := TVarConv.NullableFloat(value);
          if not VarIsNull(value) then rprop.SetValue(obj, TValue.FromVariant(value));
        end;
      tkChar, tkString, tkWChar, tkLString, tkWString, tkUString:
        begin
          rprop.SetValue(obj, TValue.FromVariant(VarToStr(value)));
        end;
      tkEnumeration:
        begin
          if rprop.PropertyType.Name = 'Boolean' then
            value := TVarConv.NullableBool(value)
          else
            value := null;
          if not VarIsNull(value) then rprop.SetValue(obj, TValue.FromVariant(value));
        end;
      tkVariant:
        //Here I transmit the TDateTime value
        rprop.SetValue(obj, TValue.FromVariant(value));
        //An object receives Float
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: `Variant` and `OleVariant` are two different types. Code that is not *directly* interacting with ActiveX/COM objects should not be using `OleVariant`. That has nothing to do with RTTI. Your `value` parameter should be using `Variant` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It does at least in Delphi code. When I put a `TDateTime` value into an OleVariant the compiler properly inserts a call to `VarFromTDateTime` and `TValue.FromVariant` properly executes the `varDate` case label.

Comment: If you explicitly set `VarAsType(value,varDate)` when calling `TValue.FromVariant()`, does it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue here is that `TValue.FromVariant` is internally "unpacking" the passed `Variant` , storing the underlying value inside the `TValue`. In your case it properly notices that a `TDateTime` is stored in the `Variant` and stores it as `TDateTime`.

When you pass that `TValue` containing a `TDateTime` (which is of TypeKind `tkFloat`) down to the `SetValue` of the `TRttiProperty` it does a conversion to the type of the property which is `Variant` - see `System.Rtti.Conv2Variant`. This method ignores the fact that a `tkFloat` can be a `TDateTime` but simply puts a `Variant` that stores a float into the result.

The solution is simple: don't use `TValue.FromVariant` but simply `TValue.From<Variant>(value)`. That way you are storing the Variant value inside the TValue and pass it as it is without any unnecessary implicit type conversions to the setter.

Reported as https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-21176